# iOS web app body color

Tags: ios, css, web-applications

I have an iOS web app. I have the following css applied

```css
body{
    background-color:red;   
}
```

This red background shows up in iOS safari but when I save it to the home screen the background is white.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using the RGB color?

Comment: @user3258468 I have also tried this. Neither work

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I wasn't sure whether you were talking about the home screen icon or the website background color.

**1.** If you mean that the icon is getting white you can fix this by a meta tag:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="the/url/of/your/icon-image" />
```

**2.** If you mean that the background color is white instead of red, I would suggest that you just put it as inlin styling, like this:

```
<body style="background-color:red">
```

Or you can use the background property, so your css will be like this:

```
body {
  background:red;
}
```

I hope this answered your question and that it will work!